# Regex: matching up first occurence before special characters (|,-,/...)

Tags: regex

I have product id on a sheet in two parts separated by special characters
I have several pattern, I can't find a solution that works for all my patterns, I would like to keep only the text before the "-", "|", space can be everywhere

```
 aaa23-rerez3
 dfds12|gdflk 132
 ds123 fdsf-123 gad
 sa 123,fdsg 123
```

I found this regex :

```
.*\w
```

working for some pattern but didn't work for pipe | and -

many thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps like this? `^[^\r\n|-]+` https://regex101.com/r/TRiBfx/1 or `^\s*(?:\w+\s*)+` https://regex101.com/r/Jj7okd/1

Answer (score 0):

Allow spaces, but separate if special character found.

```js
["aaa23-rerez3", "dfds12|gdflk 132", "ds123 fdsf-123 gad", "sa 123,fdsg 123"].forEach(x => console.log(x, x.split(/[^\d\w\s]/g)))
```

Separates space also.

```js
["aaa23-rerez3", "dfds12|gdflk 132", "ds123 fdsf-123 gad", "sa 123,fdsg 123"].forEach(x => console.log(x, x.split(/\W/g)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To match only the text before the | or - you can use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match any char except the listed in the character class.

```
^[^|-]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpI37n/1)

If the spaces can be anywhere and you also want to match those along with only word characters:

```
^\s*(?:\w+\s*)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jj7okd/1)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following regular expression works for you. I tested it and it worked for all your patterns.

```
^([^-\|\s]+)(?=[-\|\s].*$)
```